# How do you convert a time series dataframe into a binnable (thus, plottable) dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe

```
user, organization, logintime, logouttime
a, 1, 2017-01-01 00:22:33, 2017-01-01 00:23:45
b, 2, 2017-01-01 00:28:33, 2017-01-01 00:32:45
c, 3, 2017-01-01 00:44:12, 2017-01-01 00:55:45
d, 1, 2017-01-01 00:44:33, 2017-01-01 01:23:45
...
a, 1, 2017-05-02 23:32:11, 2017-05-03 00:12:22
```

How do I convert this into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
organization, dataframe
a, [month 1: 32, month 2: 42, ..., month 12: 82]
b, [month 1: 22, month 2: 11, ..., month 12: 12]
...
```

where the value for each month represents the count of login times during that month.

Thanks!

P.S. If anyone knows a simple way of plotting the original dataframe and specifying time bins without having to process it into the new dataframe, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer to return a DataFrame as follows:

```
In [11]: df  # important that logintime is a datetime64 column
Out[11]:
  user  organization           logintime           logouttime
0    a             1 2017-01-01 00:22:33  2017-01-01 00:23:45
1    b             2 2017-01-01 00:28:33  2017-01-01 00:32:45
2    c             3 2017-01-01 00:44:12  2017-01-01 00:55:45
3    d             1 2017-01-01 00:44:33  2017-01-01 01:23:45
4    a             1 2017-05-02 23:32:11  2017-05-03 00:12:22

In [12]: df.set_index("logintime").groupby(["user", pd.TimeGrouper("M")]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[12]:
logintime  2017-01-31  2017-05-31
user
a                   1           1
b                   1           0
c                   1           0
d                   1           0
```

where this is read as "user a had 1 login in the month ending 2017-01-31".

---

To explain the steps: we first set the index (so as to allow a groupby with the logintime *and* user) and second to take the size of the group (the number of logins) for each user-month group.